# Run a specific task from an Ansible role without running the role's meta dependencies

Tags: ansible

I have a role 'dpi' that has one role it depends on:

//roles/dpi/meta/main.yml

```
---
dependencies:
  - role: foo_role
```

Additionally, I have written one task in the 'dpi' role as:

//roles/dpi/tasks/foo_task.yml

I have a top-level playbook (run_xyz_update.yml) which I am using to call just the foo_task.yml from the dpi role:

```
---
- name: Run xyz update on dpi hosts
  hosts: dpi
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: dpi
        tasks_from: foo_task.yml
```

Whenever I run the top-level playbook, the role foo_role also get called and executes as it is defined as a dependency in the meta/main.yml.

Is there a way to just run the foo_task.yml which is in //roles/dpi/tasks/foo_task.yml from the top-level playbook (run_xyz_update.yml) without executing the roles' dependencies?

Any sort of help is really appreciated.

I tried the below:

I tried commenting out the //roles/dpi/meta/main.yml and then did a test run of the top-level playbook (run_xyz_update.yml) as it is, and I am able to run just the task //roles/dpi/tasks/foo_task.yml and it performs the work I am trying to do on the 'dpi' hosts without an issue.